# Python regular expression

Tags: python, regex, nfa

I have an expression like:

```
^(?P<stereo1>/?|\\\\?)(?P<bond1>|=?|\.|#?)(?P<number1>[0-9%]*)(?P<branching>[()]*)(?P<stereo2>/?|\\\\?)(?P<bond2>|=?|\.|#?)(?P<number2>[0-9%]*)$
```

And suppose we have a string `'\1'`
After:

```
re.match(regexp, string)
```

`stereo2 = '\'` and `number2=1`.

My question is: why `stereo1 != '\'` and `'number1' != '1'`?

Also when we have string '/1'

```
re.match(regexp,string)
```

Output: stereo1 = '/', number1 = '1'

Comment: The significance of the backslashes depends on how this string is quoted. Is the regex in a raw string `r'...'` or a plain string `'...'`? (I'm guessing the latter.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a pattern contains an alternation, the regex engine tries to find a match with each branches from the leftmost to the last branch. It is the default behaviour of NFA engines. So, if there is a match with the leftmost branch other branches are not tested.

**What's happening in your particular case?**

`(?P<stereo1>/?|\\\\?)` succeeds with its first branch `/?` and matches the empty string (since the slash is optional), and the second branch is never tested.

When `(?P<stereo2>/?|\\\\?)` is reached, the same scenario happens, but when the regex engine arrived to the end anchor `$`, the pattern fails. Then the regex engine backtracks until `(?P<stereo2>/?|\\\\?)` and tests the second branch that succeeds.

Note: a DFA regex engine has a different behaviour, it tests each branches and keeps the branch that has the larger result.

So if you want to capture the backslash with the `stereo1` group, you only need to permute the branches: `(?P<stereo1>\\\\?|/?)`